# How to connect two docker containers running on the same host?

Tags: docker, hadoop

I have **two docker containers running**

```
   docker ps
```

results

```
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS    PORTS NAMES

  0bfd25abbfc6        f_service:latest    "/usr/local/start-fl   13 seconds ago      Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   flume

  6a1d974f4e3e        h_service:latest    "/usr/local/start-al   2 minutes ago       Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   hadoop
```

Hadoop services are running in hadoop container [i.e datanode, namenode, jobtracker, tasktracker, secondarynamenode]

Flume services are running on flume contianer [i.e flume-agent]

I want to run hadoop commands on flume container.[i.e hadoop fs -ls /] How to do it? Any ideas?

I tried linking but i fail to achieve it.

RUN COMMAND for the containers:

```
  docker run -it --name hadoop -p 8080:8080 h_service

  jps on hadoop container shows all hadoop services

  docker run -it -p 8081:8081 --name flume --link hadoop:hadoop f_service

  jps on flume shows
  jps and Application.[which is flume i guess]
```

If i execute any hadoop commands inside flume container, i am getting the following error

```
 mkdir: Call From 282fc55ec08d/172.17.5.236 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org
 /hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

`telnet localhost 8020`

unable to connect to remotehost. same for 8080 also.

`netstat` inside flume container

```
 netstat -na
 Active Internet connections (servers and established)
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
 Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
 Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
```

netstat on hadoop container shows

```
    netstat
    Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
    tcp        0      0 localhost:49096         localhost:8020          TIME_WAIT
    tcp        0      0 localhost:49079         localhost:8020          ESTABLISHED
    tcp        0      0 localhost:8020          localhost:49079         ESTABLISHED
    tcp        0      0 c0c82bab5efd:54003      likho.canonical.com:80  TIME_WAIT
    tcp6       0      0 localhost:8021          localhost:40735         ESTABLISHED
    tcp6       0      0 localhost:40735         localhost:8021          ESTABLISHED
    Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
    Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9223040
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9223013
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9222782
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9222116
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9221761
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9221758
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9221302
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9221284
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9220884
    unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9220877
```

Where localhost:8020, i guess 8020 is from the specification of core-site.xml

Answer (score 5):

This one has a simple solution. First, if you want to connect to port 8020 of your hadoop container, you should make sure that that port is exposed as well. Second, these containers each have their own loopback interface (localhost) and IP addresses. They are connected through the bridge network docker0 to the host's eth0 interface. So, you need to use the IP address that Docker injects into the flume container.

So these will start the containers properly:

```
docker run -it --name hadoop --expose 8080 --expose 8020 h_service
docker run -it --name flume --link hadoop:had00p -p 8081:8081 f_service
```

But you will need to tell flume to connect to hadoop at "had00p" instead of "localhost." I used had00p here just to distinguish the alias it will have inside the container from the container name that you gave the container running hadoop.

Here is a plain example:

```
docker run -d --name container_a --expose 8080 busybox:latest nc -l 0.0.0.0 8080
docker run --rm --link container_a:dep_alias busybox:latest env
docker run --rm --link container_a:dep_alias busybox:latest cat /etc/hosts
```

When Docker creates application links it injects a number of environment variables and adds a hostname to the /etc/hosts file of the linked container. It will also add firewall rules to allow communication between the two containers if you have inter-container communication disabled.

Comment: I tried it already. The same run command i posted in my ques. What is the diff btw our commands?

Comment: The first command I provided exposes 8020 on the hadoop container. The rest of the explanation details how from inside the flume container, localhost refers to the flume container, not the host machine. Anywhere you want to reference the container that is running hadoop, you have to use the alias that you gave that container. Using your command that would just be "hadoop" with mine it is "had00p"